# RSS 2.0 and Atom 1.0: Required headers?

Tags: php, rss, atom-feed

I have a pretty basic question for yall:

What are the **required headers** for an Atom 1.0 feed?

Also, what are the **required headers** for an RSS 2.0 feed?

I know that you can set headers for a sitemap (XML document) that way:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-control: private');
header('Expires: -1');
```

What would be the correct syntax for those two?

Cheers.

PS. I thought it was quite silly to make two separate questions considering they're both so similar...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct header Content-Type header for an Atom feed is [application/atom+xml](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/atom+xml). However, Chromium does not handle it correctly ([Issue 104358: RSS feeds are not parsed correctly](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104358)).

The most compatible header is `text/xml;charset=UTF-8`, which will cause the feed to be parsed correctly by most clients. Note that you should be encoding your feed in UTF8.

```php
header('Content-type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
```

In regards to the other headers, they are just telling the client not to cache the feed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So you say I should include your piece of code alongside my 3 other header no-cache rules? And encode my feed to be UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, that will work fine. And yes, the feed should be UTF-8 encoded.